# Is it not possible to get post vars from ipn on localhost?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have searched a lot in google about using ipn(paypal) in localhost. However i wasnt' able to find any solution. It is even possible to get IPN post vars ?? I tried this 
`http://locahost/web_folder/page.php` in notify url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make your webserver publicly-accessible in order to use IPN. IPN is **not** a return-based mechanism (PDT does that). Instead, PayPal automatically pings your server when a transaction comes in.

PayPal's localhost is not your localhost. In order for PayPal to accurately ping the right server, you'll need to make it publicly open and set your IPN URL as the right, outside-accessible URL.

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Sebastian thx for the quick reply. Could define me about making your webserver publicly-accessible in order to use IPN ? Sory but coudn't get it.

Comment: Get on your router/access point and forward port 80 to your current computer. Then just give paypal your own IP address (WAN IP, that is) instead of localhost in the URL.